# HTML and CSS breaks when I change screen size

Tags: html, css, formatting

When I access my website using my macOS computer, everything looks fine at first glance. However, things take a turn for the worse when I attempt to adjust the screen size or zoom in and out. The carefully crafted formatting and layout I've worked hard to create suddenly break down, leading to a messy and undesirable user experience.

I've spent countless hours researching and troubleshooting this issue, but despite my best efforts, I've been unable to find a solution. It's been quite a frustrating journey, to say the least.

I'm reaching out to the online community in the hope that someone with more expertise in web development can lend a hand. Your help would not only resolve my current predicament but also contribute to a better user experience for visitors to my website in the future. Your assistance is greatly appreciated, and it would mean a lot to me if you could guide me toward a solution.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Spark | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=ADLaM+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/SPARK.png">   
    <script src="scripts.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body id="background">
    <div id="test">
    <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <p>Spark Pixel</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="websites.html">Websites</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div class="centered">
<h1>Welcome to</h1>
</div>
<div class="centered-below">
    <h1>
        Spark's Website!
    </h1>
</div>
<img id="homeicon" src="Images/icon.png">
<div class="version">
    <h3> <a href="updatelog.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        V1.1
    </a>
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    padding: 0px 100px;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#2E3192,#176b8f);
}
nav .logo p{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul{
    float: right;
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
nav li a{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#background {
    background-image: url("Images/background.png");
  background-size: 1440px 820px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body {
    font-family: 'ADLaM Display';
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 60px;
    animation: 1.5s fadeIn;
  }
  .centered-below {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 40px;
    animation: 1.5s fadeInBelow;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  }
  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6971ff;
  }
  h2:hover {
    font-size: 170%;
    }
    #homeicon {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 335;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
  
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 485;
      animation: 1.5s fadeInBelow3;
      transition: .4s ease;
  }
  #homeicon:hover {
    width: 500;
  }
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.version {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  animation: 1.5s fadeIn;
  font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
'''

After dedicating countless hours to troubleshooting and attempting various approaches in an ardent effort to rectify this persistent issue, I've come to the profound realization that my most prudent course of action is to seek assistance and guidance from the expansive and knowledgeable community of developers on Stack Overflow. While it would undoubtedly be immensely beneficial if a benevolent soul could generously furnish me with the meticulously rectified code snippet, I am also wholeheartedly appreciative of any invaluable insights and direction that any esteemed member of the Stack Overflow community might graciously offer to illuminate the path toward resolution for this perplexing conundrum.

Apologies if the images aren't loading correctly; they're stored on my computer, which can cause issues when you access the website remotely. I'm aware this might be confusing or frustrating. If you have any suggestions or encounter other problems, please let me know. Your feedback is important, and I want to improve the website's user experience for everyone.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! In your HTML you have elements defined below closing `</body>` tag which is not allowed. Your CSS `@keyframes fadeIn { 0% {..}` is missing a closing `}` and `animation: 1.5s fadeInBelow3` adresses unknown animation `fadeInBelow3` (probably instead of defined `fadeIn`). Correct those first and see if your issues have been resolved.

Comment: Just did that, but it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no alternative to learning the principles of CSS and layout if you want to build web pages. There are lots of "brittle" aspects to your code, like using `position: fixed`. You are better off finding a book on the basics of CSS and working through it (it may only take a few days), just so you understand the basics of layout, responsive design etc. While building a layout, it's essential to play around with the browser at each step to see how things respond at various screen sizes. Doig so at the end is way too late.